# how to understand about reducing time complexity on 0~1 knapsack

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

As for 0~1 knapsack problem,

```
f[i][v]=max{f[i-1][v],f[i-1][v-c[i]]+w[i]}
```

c[i] means the cost of ith goods,
w[i] means the value of ith goods.

And I read one doc,which said the time complexity can be optimization,especially when V is larger.as below

```
 i=1...N

 v=V...0
```

can be changed to

```
 i=1...n        

bound=max{V-sum{w[i..n]},c[i]}        

 v=V...bound
```

what does it mean?How can V(the maximum of bag) minus sum of w[i](the value of goods)?

Really confuse,or something wrong on this doc?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say whose complexity you are optimizing. Are you using dynamic programming? If so, this could mean that you don't need to calculate `f[i][v]` for small values of v, because you won't need those values to find the optimum.

Even if you put all goods from `i + 1` to `n` in the knapsack, you still have a capacity of `V - sum{c[i+1..n]}` left, so you don't need to solve the subproblem `i` (restricted to goods `1..i`) with a capacity smaller than that.

If you need a more formal answer, please describe the problem, as well as the algorithm being used, with more details.