# Reducing time complexity of Knapsack 0~1 while using DP algorithm

Tags: c, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm using DP algorithm, i.e. storing sub-problem values in 2D array where one axis

means `n` items and other - `w` values from  `0` to `W` where `W` is the maximum

capacity of knapsack. Therefore `T[n-1][W]` value is the optimum I need to

calculate. I've read in other sources that time complexity of this algorithm is

`O(nW)`. My quesiton would be: is it possible to reduce this time complexity even more?

I found other answer which talks about pretty much same thing but I can't understant it without example: [how to understand about reducing time complexity on 0~1 knapsack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242909/how-to-understand-about-reducing-time-complexity-on-01-knapsack)

I tells that we de not need to to calculate `T[i][w]` with small `w` values as they are not used in the optimum, but I can't get this properly, could anyone give detailed and visual example? This would benefit me a lot.

Comment: I think you mean O(nw), not O(nW), even though it makes no real difference asymptotically (w = W+1).

Comment: This source tells it is O(nW): http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/

Comment: Asymptotically it doesn't matter so it is correct to say O(nw) or O(nW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2D array you're trying to fill is of size `n` by `W` (actually, W+1 since the values go from `0..W`, but off-by-one doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity here). Therefore, to fill that array, you would need to do at least `n*W` work (even if you just initialize the array to all zeroes!).

Therefore, Θ(nW) (tightly bound, which is both O(nW) and Ω(nW)) is the best you can do in terms of asymptotic algorithmic time complexity.

This is what makes the dynamic programming solution so cool, is that you spend constant time on each element of the solution array (in this case, 2D) doing some constant work, from the bottom up (contrast this to the complexity of the top-down recursive solution!).

Comment: Thank you, my lecturer asked as a requirement to make a program which solves this problem but he also required to add some limitations to sorting out process to eliminate the total number of sorts and processes, but I guess this DP technique itself will be limitation compared to the recursive sub-problem algorithm or just pure brute force checking all `2^n` subsets

Comment: Yes, way better than the recursive and permutation algorithms! Recursive can sometimes be OK as long as you memoize your solutions.